# Bibliography with numbered style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, numbering

I am writing a paper and I need the references to be numbered, all the references are in a `.bib` file, I am using the journal template + `bibtex`, the packages I am using are:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\newcounter{bibcount}
```

The journal commands are:

```
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2016}
\begin{document}
```

Then:

```
\bibliography{mybibfile}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Now the pdf file is not appearing when I run, I have errors of:

- Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
- Overfull \hbox (10.09238pt too wide) in paragraph
- `h' float specifier changed to`ht'.
- Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

The complete code (MWE):

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}          
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
        \newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em                         b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

        \def\volumeyear{2016}
        %% Symbol and math packages
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{bm}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{gensymb}

        %% Figure packages
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{subcaption}
        \usepackage{capt-of}
        \usepackage{natbib}
        \usepackage{hyperref,url}
        \newcounter{bibcount}
        \newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em 
         b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
        \def\volumeyear{2016}
        \begin{document}

        \section{Introduction}
        A very very very long introduction.

        \section{Figure}
        \begin{figure}[htb!] 
        \centering 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.23,clip]{f1.png}
        \caption{f1 cap}
        \label{fig:f1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \qquad
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\linewidth}
        \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.21,clip]{f2.png}
       \caption{f2 cap}
       \label{fig:f2}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{ f1 and f2}
       \label{fig:f1f2}
       \end{figure}

       \section{Table}
       \begin{table}[h]
        \small\sf\centering
        \caption{abc\label{tab1}}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        abc&a &b & c \\
        \midrule
        \texttt{1}&1 &1   & 1 \\
        \texttt{2}&2  & 2   & 2\\
        \texttt{3}&3     & 3     & 3  \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}\\[10pt]
        \end{table}


        Citing reference \cite{R1}, reference \cite{R2} and reference \cite{R3}.

        \bibliography{bibsample}{}
        \bibliographystyle{sageV}
        \end{document}
```

In the `bibsample.bib` file we have:

```
@article{R1,
title = "A Guide to Latex",
journal = "Addison-Wesley",
volume = "1",
number = "1",
pages = "1 - 2",
year = "2003",,
author = "Kopka H and Daly PW",
}

@article{R2,
title = "LaTeX: a Document Preparation System",
journal = "Addison-Wesley",
volume = "1",
number = "1",
pages = "1 - 2",
year = "1994",,
author = "Lamport",
}



@article{R3,
title = "The  LaTeX  Companions",
journal = "Addison-Wesley",
volume = "1",
number = "1",
pages = "1 - 2",
year = "1994",,
author = "Mittelbach F and Goossens M",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your given code and bib file are several errors, for example the order of calling packages (`hyperref` should be the last one in your case, or do not write `,,` in your bib entrys, `,` is needed ...).

Because I do not have your used class and style I changed them to class `article` and style `plainnat` and I added option `numbers` to `natbib` to get numbered bib entrys in your bibliography.

Please study my changes in the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have a compilable MWE with bib file and TeX code):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{R1,
  title = "A Guide to Latex",
  journal = "Addison-Wesley",
  volume = "1",
  number = "1",
  pages = "1 - 2",
  year = "2003",
  author = "Kopka H and Daly PW",
}
@article{R2,
  title = "LaTeX: a Document Preparation System",
  journal = "Addison-Wesley",
  volume = "1",
  number = "1",
  pages = "1 - 2",
  year = "1994",
  author = "Lamport",
}
@article{R3,
  title = "The  LaTeX  Companions",
  journal = "Addison-Wesley",
  volume = "1",
  number = "1",
  pages = "1 - 2",
  year = "1994",
  author = "Mittelbach F and Goossens M",
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}%[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[%
  colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red
]{hyperref}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em 
  b}\kern-.08em
  T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2016}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
A very very very long introduction.

\section{Figure}
\begin{figure}[htb!] 
\centering 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{1\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.23,clip]{example-image-a}
    \caption{f1 cap}
    \label{fig:f1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\linewidth}
    \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.21,clip]{example-image-b}
   \caption{f2 cap}
   \label{fig:f2}
\end{subfigure}
   \caption{ f1 and f2}
   \label{fig:f1f2}
\end{figure}

\section{Table}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \small\sf\centering
    \caption{abc\label{tab1}}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    abc&a &b & c \\
    \midrule
    \texttt{1}&1 &1   & 1 \\
    \texttt{2}&2  & 2   & 2\\
    \texttt{3}&3     & 3     & 3  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\\[10pt]
\end{table}


Citing reference \cite{R1}, reference \cite{R2} and reference \cite{R3}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % sageV
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf file:

[image: resulting pdf]